# How do I get OnPropertyChanged to trigger on Orientation change by user?

Tags: .net, maui, orientation-changes, maui-community-toolkit

I can get the device orientation and set a value for it in the constructor. It works as expected. But when user changes orientation of device OnChanged event does not trigger. I am probably wrong about how this all works. But I kind of expected the OnChanged event to trigger and update the displayed information when orientation changes?

TabletPodcastViewModel.cs

```
namespace NerdNewsNavigator2.ViewModel.Tablet;

public partial class TabletPodcastViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region Properties
    readonly TwitService _twitService;
    [ObservableProperty]
    int _orientation;
    public ObservableCollection<Podcast> Podcasts { get; set; } = new();
    #endregion
    public TabletPodcastViewModel(TwitService twit)
    {
        this._twitService = twit;
        _ = GetPodcasts();
        this._orientation = OnDeviceOrientationChange();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device orientation is: " + Orientation);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Orientation));
    }

    #region Get the Podcast and set the Podcast List
    async Task GetPodcasts()
    {
        var podcastList = await TwitService.GetListOfPodcasts();
        foreach (var item in podcastList)
        {
            var temp = await Task.FromResult(FeedService.GetFeed(item));
            Podcasts.Add(temp);
        }
    }
    #endregion
    public int OnDeviceOrientationChange()
    {
        if (DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait) { return 2; }
        else return 3;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Tap(string url)
    {
        var encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TabletShowPage)}?Url={encodedUrl}");
    }
}
```

Here is TAbletPodcastPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace NerdNewsNavigator2.View.Tablet;

public partial class TabletPodcastPage : ContentPage
{
   public TabletPodcastPage(TabletPodcastViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Here is TabletPodcastPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:NerdNewsNavigator2.Model"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:NerdNewsNavigator2.ViewModel.Tablet"
             x:Class="NerdNewsNavigator2.View.Tablet.TabletPodcastPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:TabletPodcastViewModel"
               Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True"
             Title="{Binding Orientation}">
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="False"></BackButtonBehavior>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Podcasts}" Margin="5" BackgroundColor="White" SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="{Binding Orientation}"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Podcast">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="30,400,*" ColumnDefinitions="400">
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:TabletPodcastViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Url}"/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Label  Grid.Row="0"
                        Text="{Binding Title}" 
                        TextColor="Black" 
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="16" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="1"
                    Aspect="AspectFit" 
                    MaximumHeightRequest="400" 
                    MaximumWidthRequest="400" 
                    Source="{Binding Image}">
                    </Image>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2"
                           Margin="5"
                           Text="{Binding Description}" 
                           FontSize="12" 
                           TextColor="Black" 
                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: *"I kind of expected the OnChanged event to trigger"* Find the doc for the event that occurs when Orientation changes. Use that event or method override. Add that code to question. Modify that code to do whatever you need, inside the method that is triggered when Orientation changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading ToolkitmakerSteve's comment I went and found the doc for Orientation changes, I then figured out how to get it working!

Here is fixed TabletPodcastViewModel.cs:

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
// See the LICENSE file in the project root for more information.


namespace NerdNewsNavigator2.ViewModel.Tablet;

public partial class TabletPodcastViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    #region Properties
    readonly TwitService _twitService;
    [ObservableProperty]
    int _orientation;
    private DisplayInfo MyMainDisplay { get; set; } = new();

    public ObservableCollection<Podcast> Podcasts { get; set; } = new();
    #endregion
    public TabletPodcastViewModel(TwitService twit)
    {
        this._twitService = twit;
        _ = GetPodcasts();
        DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfoChanged += DeviceDisplay_MainDisplayInfoChanged;
        this._orientation = OnDeviceOrientationChange();
      //  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device orientation is: " + Orientation);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Orientation));
    }

    #region Get the Podcast and set the Podcast List
    async Task GetPodcasts()
    {
        var podcastList = await TwitService.GetListOfPodcasts();
        foreach (var item in podcastList)
        {
            var temp = await Task.FromResult(FeedService.GetFeed(item));
            Podcasts.Add(temp);
        }
    }
    #endregion
    private void DeviceDisplay_MainDisplayInfoChanged(object? sender, DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyMainDisplay = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyMainDisplay));
        Orientation = OnDeviceOrientationChange();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Orientation));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device orientation is: " + Orientation);
    }
    public int OnDeviceOrientationChange()
    {
        if (DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation == DisplayOrientation.Portrait) { return 2; }
        else return 3;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Tap(string url)
    {
        var encodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TabletShowPage)}?Url={encodedUrl}");
    }
}
```

Here is TabletPodcastPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:NerdNewsNavigator2.Model"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:NerdNewsNavigator2.ViewModel.Tablet"
             x:Class="NerdNewsNavigator2.View.Tablet.TabletPodcastPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:TabletPodcastViewModel"
               Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             Title="">
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="True" IsVisible="False"></BackButtonBehavior>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Podcasts}" Margin="5" BackgroundColor="White" SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="{Binding Orientation}"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Podcast">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="30,400,*" ColumnDefinitions="400">
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:TabletPodcastViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Url}"/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Label  Grid.Row="0"
                        Text="{Binding Title}" 
                        TextColor="Black" 
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="16" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="1"
                    Aspect="AspectFit" 
                    MaximumHeightRequest="400" 
                    MaximumWidthRequest="400" 
                    Source="{Binding Image}">
                    </Image>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2"
                           Margin="5"
                           Text="{Binding Description}" 
                           FontSize="12" 
                           TextColor="Black" 
                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

This is working for detecting device orientation changes and applying numerical changes to span in GridItemsLayout! TY so much for the suggestion. I have been banging my head against a virtual wall trying to figure this out. I was at a loss as to how to go about figuring out what I needed to do.